# Rhino: Not All Arguments Converted During String Formatting

Tags: file-io, typeerror, rhino

I am attempting to execute a code using Rhino Python and I am having some issues with the following TypeError:

> Message: not all arguments converted during string formatting

The code I have written is meant to read point coordinates from a file "newpoints.csv" and use them as arguments for Rhino Python's 'AddLine' function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs

file = open("C:\\Users\\Seshane Mahlo\\Documents\\MSc Thesis\\newpoints.csv", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

ab = len(lines)
seq = range(0, ab-1, 2)
coordinates = []
startvals = []
stopvals = []

for line in lines:
    coords = line.split(',')
    xcoord = float(coords[0])
    ycoord = float(coords[1])
    point = (xcoord, ycoord)
    coordinates.append(point)

starts = range(0, ab-2, 2)
ends = range(1, ab+1, 2)

for i,j in zip(starts, ends):
   strt = coordinates[i]
   stp = coordinates[j]
   rs.AddLine(start=strt,end=stp)
```

Comment: Please provide more context for the error message if you can. It's not clear where your code is throwing this TypeError from the information given.

Comment: @GGordonWorleyIII The error seems to be triggered by Line 27 Traceback:
  line 348, in coerce3dpoint, "C:\Users\Seshane Mahlo\AppData\Roaming\McNeel\Rhinoceros\5.0\Plug-ins\IronPython (814d908a-e25c-493d-97e9-ee3861957f49)\settings\lib\rhinoscript\utility.py"
  line 310, in AddLine, "C:\Users\Seshane Mahlo\AppData\Roaming\McNeel\Rhinoceros\5.0\Plug-ins\IronPython (814d908a-e25c-493d-97e9-ee3861957f49)\settings\lib\rhinoscript\curve.py"
  line 27, in <module>, "C:\Users\Seshane Mahlo\AppData\Roaming\McNeel\Rhinoceros\5.0\scripts\drawlines.py"

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small mistake in your code here:

```
starts = range(0, ab-2, 2)
ends = range(1, ab-1, 2)
```

which should be

```
starts = range(0, ab-1, 2)
ends = range(1, ab, 2)
```

because the last element you get from the range function is one less than the stop argument.

But what is causing the error is that you are trying to add a line, which is composed of two 3d points using a 2-tuple (x,y)

To fix this change:

```
point = (xcoord, ycoord)
```

to

```
point = (xcoord, ycoord, 0)
```

or whatever you want your z-coordinate to be.